# Google Suspended My App After Update ... Can I Upload the Same Again

Tags: android, google-play, suspend, developer-console

Yesterday I put an Update in my Store Listing and Put Couple of Tags and Google Decided to Suspend my app.
I want to know that What If I upload the same Application( Icon,Old Description etc )
Will They Suspend that Too???

Comment: maybe You have to much similar tags........You don´t need to update it, just rewrite Your description but read the developer guidelines for publishing apps first....

Comment: I used only 2 tags.
Google Suspended it.
Now All I have got is to upload it again

Comment: There must be a reason for suspending Your app. Copyrighted Images, also tags which does not match the guidelines (for example porn, hate, terror or similar). Don´t they gave You a reason for suspending inside Your developer console? Usually, by deleting these violences, You app will be "freed"...

Comment: Yes,
Reason was intellectual property and impersonation..
I put these ( All Video Downloader, Tube Downloader ) as tags
This update was about 10 days after previous update.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about the policies of an app distribution channel, not programming. Please see [this Meta post](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272165/are-developer-centric-questions-about-application-stores-on-topic) about what is and is not on-topic for Stack Overflow about app distribution channels like the Play Store.

Comment: Okey.
Thanks to all for helping me

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can upload app again but you have to change package name. And make sure their is no copyright image or logo in app otherwise they will suspend app again.

Comment: Thanks Umar,
My App was going fine until I put an update to store listing that leads to suspension.So I think it doesn't contain anything wrong.

Comment: Ok fine but there will be some reason thats why they suspend app. you can check again your graphics on https://www.tineye.com/

Comment: Icon :
http://tineye.com/search/31db342cf5aed49a8fc6eda3f1ce9172a0cd4c42/
PROMOTIONAL Graphics:
http://tineye.com/search/03e3077b9a145bbe95334581c2899c88f674cf47/